# Addition some float number and show the result with space separator and coma as decimal separator

Tags: java, android, textview, decimalformat

Hello I have one issue I want to addition some float numbers and show the result with space separator and coma for decimal part like 1 033 010,13

Please how can I proceed ?

Comment: Is that a regional convention? If so, check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do  this:

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
    .format(1234567890.55).replaceAll(","," ").replace(".",","));
```

Comment: That ok for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `NumberFormat`, example:

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(1234567890))

1,234,567,890
```

You'll need to change `Locale.US` to yours of course.

**EDIT**

if no standard format out there supports what you want, go custom!

```
Float.parseFloat("1234567890")
```

Now you got a string... use `StringBuilder`

some type of loop to scan for all your `" "` and `","` indicies

`numstr.insert(index, " ")` and `numstr.insert(index, ",")`

back to string `numstr.toString()`

Comment: Not good, need a result like this 10 000 000,34

Comment: if it's going to be so custom that all standard formats don't support it, then you'll need to make your own function to change it yourself.